# What if standing by ORM design clutters my database?

Tags: database-design

I have a system where users can lay claim to objects of various types--

```
Teams, 
Facilities, 
Equipment, 
Personnel
```

A user is represented by "Cell"--a self-contained slice of the organizational pie. After they create a Claim for one of those objects, they can then set the status for their Claims. Seems simple enough, right?

Well, here's where the headache begins. Those things form a loose hierarcy as described above.  Super users create templates for each of those objects using a handful of link tables.  A Team can be comprised of Facilities, Equipment, and Personnel, Facilities are comprised of Equipment and Personnel, and a Cell can create a claim for anything they want.   Tremendously flexible, but annoying on the back end.

Team, Facility, Equipment, and Personnel have the exact same columns:

```
Id, 
Name, 
Description, 
DateCreated, 
CreatedById, 
IsArchived
```

In keeping with ORM concepts, each of those is an individual table right now.  The REAL pain comes when the user needs to create a Claim.  The hierarchy will leave us with the following tables:

```
TeamClaim, FacilityClaim, EquipmentClaim, PersonnelClaim, TeamFacilityClaim, 
TeamEquipmentClaim, TeamPersonnelClaim, so on and so forth.
```

Plus another Status table per each of those claim tables.

Obviously, this is just garbage.

So, I changed my design to a single table, called ClaimableItem.  It has the columns as defined above, plus a "Type" column; that's just a three letter representation.  Then I created a single table called Claim--it has all the necessary columns, with a composite unique key defined as ClaimableItemId and ClaimableItemType.

I've already tested this with my C# code.  EF4 might hate reusing keys, but a minor workaround (hack) made it relatively easy to get done; I can change all of my model, view, and controller code to accommodate the new stuff in about an hour.

My question (finally) is this: **Is my new single table crap design?**  It's keeping my database from being cluttered with tables and would actually expedite adding new ClaimableItem types--no need to create new objects for them.  My problem is that the three-letter representation isn't intuitive worth a crap, has to be handled in code, and it kind of chafes against the purist in me.

**Anyone have a better idea how to do this?**

Comment: Why does your Type have to be just 3 letters?  Make it large enough (10 - 15) so that the Type is recognizable.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Actually, I'd advise against it. A simple integer (or even just CHAR(1) or byte depending on DBMS) with a set of well-known values (effectively an enum) would require minimal space and therefore play nicer with caching. There is no particular reason why this field should be human-readable.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic: I agree.  The human readable names should go in a domain table, and the integer id's would go in the data rows.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Thanks.  Domain table hit what I was looking for on the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a great case for inheritance. Have `Teams, Facilities, Equipment, Personnel` inherit from `ClaimableItem` and make a `Claim` reference `ClaimableItem`.

This is actually very similar to what you propose. You said:

> So, I changed my design to a single table, called ClaimableItem. It
>   has the columns as defined above, plus a "Type" column; that's just a
>   three letter representation. Then I created a single table called
>   Claim--it has all the necessary columns, with a composite unique key
>   defined as ClaimableItemId and ClaimableItemType.

I don't think you need a composite foreign key. They `Type` discriminator column can sit in the `ClaimableItem` table.

Is this *pure*? I think it is. It is a perfect case for inheritance.

A final comment: Go with your intuition in such cases. If you feel that a solution is crap and you notice yourself wishing for something simpler, go for it. Trade-offs are sometimes unclear choices and developers learn over time to instinctively judge whats right in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a few false assumptions.

1. it is *NOT* "keeping with ORM concepts" to create tables in any specific way.
2. it is *NOT* necessary to have seperate tables for every type
3. it is *NOT* necessary to have link tables all over the place.

Most ORM's support a form of inheritence that uses a column discriminator, typically a type value of some sort, which is identical to the solution you have proposed.

This is a very practical and pragmatic way to design your data model and database, however it's not exactly a "pure" database design concept because you can longer use referential integrity and constraints to ensure that only certain values mean certain things.

For example, when you have a TeamClaim link table, you can (through the use of referential integrity) guarantee that every value joined is a team and a claim, because these are distinct entities in the database.

What happens if you intend to linke a team and a claim but instead link a Facility and a claim?  Oops.  And no way for the database to know you made a mistake.

This is similar to the one true lookup table problem.

But, for many people, the loss of referential integrity is a small price to pay for greater flexibility.  You just have to be very careful in your code, and don't allow people to manually muck with the tables.